# How to extend the range of a variable in idl

Tags: range, idl

I'd like to use k to calculate the times of the `for` loop executed. It would be billions of times and I tried `long64`, then after some time k became negative. Is there any other way to do this?

Sorry I think I made a wrong description. My code is a 3-layer `for` nest block and each of them is calculating 2*256^3 numbers, once the value is equal to 0, I'd like to make `k+=k`. In the end I set `print, 'k=', k` and when idl was running, I found k ran from positive to negative. I used a cluster to do the computation so it didn't take quite a long time.

Comment: I am not sure how you are doing this, but you would need to execute more than 9223372036854775807 loops before causing a `long64` variable to roll over, which would take your computer an incredible amount of time (millions of seconds at ~2.6 x 10^{9} loops per second).  Could you show a minimal working example of your code?  You could use doubles to count, but usually the `FOR` loop has its own index that it uses, so again, I am not sure what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry I think I made a wrong description. My code is a 3-layer `for` nest block and each of them is calculating 2*256^3 numbers, once the value is equal to 0, I'd like to make k+=k. In the end I made `print, 'k=', k` and when `idl` is running, I found k ran from positive to negative. I use a cluster to do the computation so it didn't take quite a long time.

Comment: Then my guess is that mgalloy is correct.  When you first define `k` make sure you define it as a `long64` variable.  IDL will automatically increase the type code to a type with "larger" dynamic range if you operate on the variable with a "larger" type (by larger I mean going from a 16 bit integer to a 32 bit long integer, for example).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not really using a `long64` for `k`. The type for the loop variable in a `for` loop comes from the start value. For example, in this case:

```
k = 0LL
for k = 0, n - 1 do ...
```

`k` is a int (16-bit) because `0` is a int. You probably want something like:

```
for k = 0LL, n - 1LL do begin ...
```